# QLabel position not updating

Tags: qt, qlabel

I am creating `QLabel` objects in my one class, and adding them to my `QList<QLabel*> *objects`. The `QList` is created in my main class with the command `objects = new QList<QLabel*>();` and then sent to the class where the objects are created and added. This `QList` is also then sent to my `movement class`. 
In my `movement class` I have a timer that detects if the `QList` is empty and if it is not, I run through all of the `QLabel` objects in the `QList`, and under some circumstances I move the `QLabel` object.

This is where my problem comes in. The code compiles perfectly and I have used debug and gone through the code, the move commands are executed perfectly and if i use `qDebud()` to display the x and y coordinate of the `QLabel` it returns the correct values however the movement is not updated on my display?
The `QLabel` gets deleted perfectly at the correct times and is removed from the screen, but the movements is not shown ?

Is there anyone with some insights into why this will be happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

> The code moves widgets and debug output shows position changed but in
>   fact some widgets are still there at previous position. Why?

There is a possibility of some widget position updates being delayed. Try using this call:

[QWidget::updateGeometry()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry)

```
for(auto* pLabel : listOfLabels)
{
   // and other actions suitable
   // pLabel->move(newPoint(x, y));
   pLabel->updateGeometry();
}
```

Comment: This seems to have no effect what so ever .
Should I implement it right after the move operation has been executed ?

Comment: Then more code of yours needed. A minimum sufficient example.